# How do I show the user the right key for variable keyboards?

Tags: keyboard

So, I have a lot of shortcuts in my game but for some keys, I don't know how to show the right mapping. Those are the keys labelled for example `OEM1` and `OEM2` in Windows. What key that maps to is different depending on what physical keyboard you are using, not just per language. `OEM1` for example is the key to the right of M on my keyboard, so comma ",". But for others, it will be a completely different character.

How do I show the user what `OEM1` is on their particular keyboard? I've seen other games do it, so it is possible.
We are not using SDL, but this does something similar I think: https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetKeyFromScancode

Comment: In order to get answers for this you should mention the library or API that you are using the query for the keys in the first place. The answer can vary wildly depending on which method your using and how that maps keys to strings :)

Comment: We are using our own engine, written in C++. I don't think we are using any library or API for this as of now.

Comment: You must be calling the operating system in some fashion, through some library or not, to find out what keys will be pressed. That is the API in question.